# How to remove all except some DOM elements in JQuery?

Tags: jquery

I would like to remove all hidden elements in a piece of the DOM, but preserving all (included hidden items) under certain class.

Here you have a (non) [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/navi2000/VWZ6B/1/):

```
<div id="init">
    <input type="hidden" name="x" value="y" />
    <ul>
        <li>Hello</li>
        <li>Bye</li>
        <li class="block">
            <ol>
                <li>First</li>
                <li>Second</li>
                <li>Third</li>
            </ol>
        </li>
        <li>Test</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS: `li { "display:none" }`

So, I'm looking for the selector that removes all hidden items except those that have a *block* class or are under a *block* class. In this case the expected result is:

```
<div id="init">
    <ul>
        <li class="block">
            <ol>
                <li>First</li>
                <li>Second</li>
                <li>Third</li>
            </ol>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I've been playing with :not operator, but no success.

Comment: Would you just like to check if the elements immediate parent has a particular class, or are do you need to travel up the parent(s) tree?

Comment: Whole subtree must remain intact

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You mean like this?

```
$(':hidden').not('.block, .block *').remove();
```

Alternatively:

```
$(':hidden:not(.block, .block *)').remove();
```

But `$.fn.not()` is a [little more reliable than `:not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)

Comment: Is it possible to replace `$('div:not(:has(video))')` with `.not` and `.has`?

Comment: @IulianOnofrei, if you have a different question, please use the "Ask Question" button at the top of the page (assuming it meets the SO guidelines).

Answer (score 0):

You can actually just use CSS:

```
li.block, li.block li { display: block }
```

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/VWZ6B/3/)

---

Or more comprehensive

```
li.block, li.block>* * { display: block }
```